# Model Create returns undefined with no creation - Sails JS

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm trying to implement the passport-facebook strategy into my application, however I seem to be running into some issues.

I can successfully call Facebook and get a response back, however when trying to save the user to my database, nothing happens.

In my code below, I want to check to see if the user already exists in the database, if they do, return their details, if they don't create a new entry.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: '123',
  clientSecret: '123',
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:1337/auth/facebook/callback',
  profileFields: ['email']
},
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value}, function(err, user){
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user || user == 'false') {
        console.log('No user found');
        console.log(profile.id);
        User.create({facebookId: profile.id, email: profile.emails[0].value}, function(err, user){
          return done(null, user, { message: 'Facebook user created'});
        })
      } else {
        console.log(user);
        return done(null, user, { message: 'User already registered'});
      }
    })
  }
));
```

I can log out the profile id fine, as well as the email, however the User.create statement does not run.

I also have passport-local implemented, and if I post the data to my user model, it creates the user just fine.

For reference, my user model looks like:

```
module.exports = {

  connection: 'someMongodbServer',

  attributes: {
    facebookId: {
      type: 'integer',
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 6,
    },
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      return obj;
    }
  },
  beforeCreate: function(user, cb) {
    if(user.password){
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            cb(err)
          } else {
            user.password = hash;
            cb();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Does anyone know where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it, was a silly mistake on my behalf.

The User model invokes the beforeCreate function to hash the password.   As I was using the Facebook strategy for Passport, there is no password for a Facebook user so I added an if statement to check for this.

```
if(user.password){
```

What I had missed was the callback in this function should their not be a password.  Solution for the beforeCreate function is:

```
  beforeCreate: function(user, cb) {
    if(user.password){
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            cb(err)
          } else {
            user.password = hash;
            cb();
          }
        });
      });
    }
    cb();
  }
```